# Latex side-by-side nested bullet points of different size

Tags: latex

I am trying to create what is shown in the following picture but without any success:

[image: Ideal Result Image Link]

Therefore, I would like to have 4 Field titles in the form of a 2x2 table where the column A is approximately double the size of column B because there exist more skills to mention.  In addition, each column contains two bullet points as indicated in the screenshot.

I tried multiple ways including:

```
% importing necessary package for side by side bullets.
\usepackage{multienum}
\newenvironment{multiitem}{%
  \multienumerate\renewcommand{\labelname}{\textbullet}%
}{%
  \endmultienumerate%
}

\begin{multiitem}
\mitemxx{Field A}{Field B}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Example
  \end{itemize}
\end{multiitem}
```

The first problem is that I want the fields to be 'empty' bullet points but `\mitemxx[] {Field A}{Field B}` does not work, therefore is not the same as `\item[]`.

Can someone show how I can do this?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the post above, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `minipage`s that are `[t]`op-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Key skills}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6667\linewidth}
  Field A
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
    \item Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
  \end{itemize}

  Field C
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
    \item Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3333\linewidth}
  Field B
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
    \item Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
  \end{itemize}

  Field D
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
    \item Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to approach this is by using a table. You will set the first column to be twice the second. Then divide your fields accordingly. For listing, you can use `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`. I have also put the table lines just to give an idea about how the layout is.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % Reduce the while space of itemize environment
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|p{4in}|p{2in}|} 
            \hline
            A & B\\\hline
            Field A & Field B\\
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
                \item A Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
            \end{itemize}                    
            &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item B Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
                \item B Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
            \end{itemize}\\
            Field C & Field D\\ 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item C Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
                \item C Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
            \end{itemize}                    
            &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item D Expert: Skill 1, 2, 3.
                \item D Advanced: Skill 4, 5, 6.
            \end{itemize}\\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```